# Extract OTP (6 digit) from SMS - Android

Tags: android, sms

I have a broadcast receiver which listens for sms. When Sms arrives I have the whole text but am concerned with only the OTP.

My challenge is how to extract the 6 digit otp. I can't use regex because sms format might change.

example " Thanks for registering your otp is 123456"

I want 123456.  sms structure can change but otp will always be a 6 digit figure

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got this working with Pattern and Matcher.

if this helps anyone (in onReceive callback of broadcast receiver) :

```
   //---This will match any 6 digit number in the message, can use "|" to lookup more possible combinations

            public Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(|^)\\d{6}");

  //---retrieve the SMS message received---

                try{
                       /**Extract sms*/
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                        for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)   //Msg Read
                        {
                            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                            msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                            msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                        }

                    /*
                    * Now extract the otp*/
                        if(msgBody!=null) 
                          {
                            Matcher m = p.matcher(msgBody);
                            if(m.find()) {
                                otp.setText(m.group(0));
                               }
                            else
                              {
                               //something went wrong
                              }
                          }
                  }catch(Excep...
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this [PinEntryEditText](https://github.com/alphamu/PinEntryEditText) , This was a very helpful resource for me.

activity_otp.xml

```
 <com.alimuzaffar.lib.pin.PinEntryEditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_pin_entry"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_14dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_14dp"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:digits="1234567890"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                android:maxLength="6"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
```

OtpActivity.java

```
public class OptActivity {

...
  @BindView(R.id.txt_pin_entry) PinEntryEditText pinEntry;

...

 @OnClick(R.id.submitOtp)
    void submitOtp(){
        if (pinEntry.length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.enter_otp_to_continue , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (pinEntry.length() < 6){
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.must_be_6_length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pinEntry.setText(null);
            return;
        }

        //Do what you want here

    }
}
```